# Manually create and add a new user to a Hyperledger Fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Without using Fabric CA, I am trying to manually create and add a new user to a Hyperledger Fabric network (a new admin that can, for example, upgrade the chaincode on a given channel).

I have been able (I think) to create the crypto files for the new user and put them in the correct folders (see below), but I have not been able to find any documentation on adding this new user. Can someone please provide an example or a link to some documentation about how to add the new user?

I am creating the new user using openssl like this:

```
openssl ecparam -in k.pem -text
openssl ecparam -in k.pem -genkey -noout -out k.key
openssl req -new -key k.key -out k.csr -outform PEM
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -CA <PATH>/ca/ca.domain-cert.pem -CAkey <PATH>/ca/ca.domain-cert.sk -in k.csr -out k-signed.pem -days 3650 -CAcreateserial
```